# How to add a set of multiple values to a key?

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary, set

I created a class which is basically a hobby book. The book can be accessed by two methods, `enter(n,h)` which takes a name and keep adding hobbies to that name(one name can have multiple hobbies). The other method returns a set of hobbies for a particular name. My hobby book is storing every hobby that I insert to one name. Can someone help me fixing it?

```
class Hobby:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dic={}
        self.hby=set()

    def enter(self,n,h):

        if n not in self.dic.items():
            self.dic[n]=self.hby
                for k in self.dic.items():
                    self.hby.add(h)

    def lookup(self,n):
        return self.dic[n]
```

I tried running following cases

```
    d = Hobby(); d.enter('Roj', 'soccer'); d.lookup('Roj')
    {'soccer'}
    d.enter('Max', 'reading'); d.lookup('Max') 
    {'reading', 'soccer'} #should return just reading
    d.enter('Roj', 'music'); d.lookup('Roj')
    {'reading', 'soccer','music'} #should return soccer and music
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you re-inventing a `dict` here? Why are you using a separate set to which you always add values, and reference it to every key which ensures that it always returns the same set on a lookup?

Don't reinvent the wheel, use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(set)
d["Roj"].add("soccer")
d["Roj"]
# {'soccer'}
d["Max"].add("reading")
d["Max"]
# {'reading'}
d["Roj"].add("music")
d["Roj"]
# {'soccer', 'music'}
```

.

**UPDATE** - If you really want to do it through your own class (and before you do, watch [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)!), you can do it as:

```
class Hobby(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.container = {}

    def enter(self, n, h):
        if n not in self.container:
            self.container[n] = {h}
        else:
            self.container[n].add(h)

    def lookup(self, n):
        return self.container.get(n, None)

d = Hobby()
d.enter("Roj", "soccer")
d.lookup("Roj")
# {'soccer'}
d.enter("Max", "reading")
d.lookup("Max")
# {'reading'}
d.enter("Roj", "music")
d.lookup("Roj")
# {'soccer', 'music'}
```

Note how no extra set is used here - every `dict` key gets its own `set` to populate.